# Use $max inside $match

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to filter the objects which will go into an aggregate chain by only working on the latest entries defined by a timestamp.

Currently I use `new Date().getTime() - (1000 * 60 * 5)` in the `$match` to find all entries within the last 5 minutes.

**Working example**

*(`fetchedAtTime` is a unix timestamp)*

```
db.getCollection('data').aggregate([
    { $match: {"fetchedAtTime": {$gte: new Date().getTime() - (1000 * 60 * 5)}} },
    { $group: {
        _id: "$name",
        latestFetchedAtTime: {$max: "$fetchedAtTime"},
        oldestFetchedAtTime: {$min: "$fetchedAtTime"}
    }}
]);
```

---

**Problem**

But I don't want to use `new Date()`. I want to subtract the 5 minutes from the most resent `fetchedAtTime` entry (for cases when the are no new entries added to the database for whatever reason).

So I tried to add the `$max` into the `$match` but none of my tries were successful.

**Non working example(s)**

*(I've put all `$match`es in one code block just for readability - tried them separately)*

```
db.getCollection('data').aggregate([
    { $match: {"fetchedAtTime": {$gte: { $subtract: [{$max: "$fetchedAtTime"}, (1000 * 60 * 5)]}}} },
    { $match: {"fetchedAtTime": {$gte: { $subtract: [new Date({$max: "$fetchedAtTime"}).getTime(), (1000 * 60 * 5)]}}} },
    { $match: {"fetchedAtTime": {$gte: new Date({$max: "$fetchedAtTime"}).getTime() - (1000 * 60 * 5)}} },
    { $group: {
        _id: "$name",
        latestFetchedAtTime: {$max: "$fetchedAtTime"},
        oldestFetchedAtTime: {$min: "$fetchedAtTime"}
    }}
]);
```

Is there a way to archive this in one aggregate chain?

Comment: `$match` does not calculate values. It's basically just the same as `.find()` and actually in most recent MongoDB versions a preceding `$match` is treated **exactly** that way and removed from the pipeline completely and processed as a regular query feeding further processing. You simply cannot "access the last date" within the same query operation. You need to run a separate query in order to return the last date on it's own, and then adjust your criteria.

Comment: Thank you @NeilLunn